# How to compare the results of two different studies?

Tags: model-comparison

> I applied Ancova on my data set (population in my country) to see
>   whether there is a relationship between a categorical independent
>   (race with three levels) and a continuous dependent (Cholesterol) when we have a covariate in the model (Age).
>
> In another study (which is done by another university in a different
>   country) they applied a method to see the relationship between race and cholesterol by considering the effect of Age in their data set (their population).
>
> Now my question is that how we can compare the results of two different studies when the variables and the research questions are the same. 
>   Also how we can compare (for example) the first level of their "race variable (race1)" with the first level of our variable (race)

Comment: I think we may need more detail for anyone to attempt an answer here. Did you both use the same model? Do you have access to the complete results from their model or just a published summary?

Comment: @ mdewey, thanks so much for your reply, Yes, we have access to both data sets and we applied the same method.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you need to add a two-level variable for study and then look at its interaction with the terms you are interested in. That will only work if you have the same levels of race in both studies.

Comment: @ mdewey, thanks so much. It means I need to combine two data sets and then create a two levels categorical variable (x3) and apply a model something like   y=race *Age *X3? Please correct me if I am wrong.